# Obtuse Angle using sine function

Tags: trigonometry

An airplane flew 490 miles at a bearing of N65°E from airport A to airport B. The plane then flew at a bearing of S38°E to airport C. Find the distance from A to C if the bearing from airport A to airport C is S60°E.

Comment: You are trying to find the distance from A to C. Could you explain what the "obtuse" angle in the title has to do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Draw triangle $ABC$. Notice that:

- $\angle A = 180^\circ - 65^\circ - 60^\circ = 55^\circ$
- $\angle B = 65^\circ + 38^\circ = 103^\circ$
- $\angle C = 180^\circ - 55^\circ - 103^\circ = 22^\circ$
- $AB = 490$ miles

So to find $AC$, you can just apply Sine Law.